# Layout shown differently across devices

Tags: android

i would like to know why my fragment layout has different dimensions when I run the app on different devices. I thought using dp was enough, but now I think i've missed something.
For istance, on my Nexus 6P it looks fine, but in the AVD Emulator's Nexus 4 it looks smaller

Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:text="@string/delete_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/moveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/deleteButton"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:text="@string/move_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/copyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:text="@string/copy_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/renameButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/moveButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/copyButton"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:text="@string/rename_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I forgot to write the code where I set the dialogFragment size.

```
    /**
     * Setting Dialog size
     */
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    // Store dimensions of the screen in `size`
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    window.setLayout((int) (size.y * 0.40), (int) (size.x * 0.60));
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of your elements width and height seems to wrap_content, so i would check the Font configured in your emulator by default, if its size is smaller, the whole content will be small.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply, I've edited my post with the code that set the fragment size. I think the problem is there

Comment: `display.getSize(size)` returns the size in pixels according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)) and the `window.setLayout` accepts in dp i guess. Try converting the pixel value you calculated to dp and then set it to `setLayout` it might work as expected. Here is a [gist for converting px to dp](https://gist.github.com/laaptu/7867851)